# Build of OpenCV getting errors, are these serious?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to Raspberry Pi (and command-line build etc..). Here's the output I got from building OpenCV:

```
pi@SamPi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
> -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
> -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
> -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
> -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2

-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed

-- Looking for io.h
-- Looking for io.h - not found
-- Looking for jbg_newlen
-- Looking for jbg_newlen - not found

-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found

-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake

-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   NO
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing:  HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES) 
-- Checking SFM deps... FALSE
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Tesseract:   NO

-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 4.9.35-v7+ armv7l
--     CMake:                       3.6.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.9.2)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 pangocairo-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pango-1.0 gobject-2.0 fontconfig freetype gthread-2.0 glib-2.0 v4l1 v4l2 avcodec avformat avutil swscale avresample dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libjpeg libwebp libtiff libjasper IlmImf libprotobuf
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching python2 python3
--     Disabled:                    world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java viz cvv hdf matlab sfm
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.25)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.42.1)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 56.1.0)
--       format:                    YES (ver 56.1.0)
--       util:                      YES (ver 54.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.0.0)
--       resample:                  YES (ver 2.1.0)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.6.0) / libv4l2 (ver 1.6.0)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.9)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.9)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.4m.so (ver 3.4.2)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.4/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build
```

A lot of these errors seem weird because I went through 1.5hrs of downloading and upgrading files specifically for this install (see tutorial

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

It's for sure I downloaded Java but it says missing. And I downloaded a bunch of stuff for image file formats but it says bu it seems i'm missing basic videoio even just regular io!!! What's going on? I've gone ahead and did the make, will I be able to get these missing files into OpenCV later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to work on virtual enviroment restart with 
    $ mkvirtualenv cv -p python2

Comment: The tutorial says this was suggested but not required?

Comment: I did try doing the environment stuff but was getting errors from changing .profile to append:export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh